# Is this ESD safe circuit?

Tags: esd

I am trying to make a AC Mains detection circuit with ESD protection. The AC switch is located 30 meters away from the circuit board.

Of the two circuits, which is better for ESD protection & mains isolation?
In Schematic One, is connecting the other end of TVS diode to AC Neutral correct?

Please suggest if there need to be any modification.

**TVS Diode**: TPD1E10B066   http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sllseb1d/sllseb1d.pdf

Schematic: One
[image]

Schematic:Two
[image]

**EDIT**: Let me explain the scenario in detail.
There are quite a lot of switches to be monitored. Inductive loads are also there. All the switches have very long wires & I am concerned about the excess energy that reach the optocoupler during switching, spikes in the line or by lightning. What is the best way to protect from such occurrences?

Comment: Are you connecting the TVS and the Zener to the low-voltage ground on purpose?

Comment: The bottom circuit with TVS and ZD to ground is **no good**. You're making a conductive path between mains (neutral and live) to ground. Best case: your GFCI will trip. Worst case: all grounded equipment will have a live voltage. Top circuit should be OK. I do not like using a ground symbol for AC neutral though, often AC neutral is **not** neutral and can have some voltage.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie There's no indication at all that signal ground is connected to earth or chassis or anything.

Comment: Regarding ESD protection: you do not actually need it. The mains live side (the LED and everything to its left) are not ESD sensitive and you're not going to touch the connections anyway as they're not safe to touch (neutral not always being without a voltage). MCU side: The only real sensitive component is the MCU and it will have proper ESD protection. No additional protection is needed.

Comment: I'd like you to explain what you mean by **ESD**. I don't think you mean the same thing as the rest of us, judging from this question. ESD is normally not a problem with line voltage circuits.

Comment: @marcelm I see two "Gnd" symbols in the bottom schematic so they're connected. If not call them Gnd1 and Gnd2. I'm assuming the optocoupler is to make the right Gnd side mains isolated which is not the case as the two Gnd are connected. So a PC connected via USB to flash the MCU will become live. That's no good.

Comment: LED just needs a reverse clamp diode,  do you want a ZCS pulse or a LPF noise filtered square wave. I would filter the AC before opto then leave output unfiltered  for square edges.

Comment: Consider Hipot test  voltage in any AC powered circuit. Then design to pass while filtering power line inductive  transients. PLT on input, not output.

Comment: Where do you expect ESD protection is needed? open circuit contact with plug-in cable charge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create a Zero Crossing Switch narrow pulse (ZCS) instead of sine to square.  Set the output R high (not 2k) to obtain CTR of 1%. Add cap to input R for <1kHz LPF to adjust phase shift but attenuate spikes.
 This is a bidirectional opto with isolation rating >5kV.

http://www.vishay.com/docs/83675/sfh620a.pdf

A Cap Voltage transformer using X rated 0.047 uF to ceramic 1 uF results in 1% sine voltage at lower impedance then series RC to opto can use low power R.

[image]
Here shown with Rin only between line and neutral may give a wider positive output pulse at zero crossing.

Alternatively, a square wave to pulse conversion just uses both inputs of an XOR gate with 1us RC delay on one input.

Answer (score 2):

Neither A or B. Remove the TVS, zener,...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fC4rG0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I agreem the TVS and zener do not harm but are overkill and not needed.

Comment: Vac threshold will vary with load , CTR and needs a LPF on input. R needs to be rated for 2kV transients minimum.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I just purged out unnecessary components as an example. OP has to calculate the CTR and other things to suit the needs. He was concerning just about ESD.

Comment: I think he meant PLT, not ESD

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I can read only ESD from his post, anyway what's a PLT?

Comment: power line transient , with standards

Answer (score 1):

The TVS, zener and 100R resistor do nothing of value. If you want to protect against transients, make sure that the 220K resistor is rated for very high breakdown voltage. For example the 1W [VR68](https://www.vishay.com/docs/28907/vr25vr37vr68.pdf) series (leaded). You need a diode inverse parallel across the LED- a 1N4148 or LL4148 is plenty good enough- those are rated for 75V or so PIV (it will see less than 1.5V) and 200mA.

Even with 5kV on the resistor only 23mA will flow, which the LED and diode will have no problem with. If the resistor arcs over, even the TVS may not be enough to preserve functionality.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't address your question but provides an alternative solution.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm3KaP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Neon opto-isolator circuit.*

[image]

*Figure 2. Neon indicator heat-shrunk to LDR.*

\$ R1 = \frac {V_{MAINS} - 90 }{I_{NEON}} \$. (90 V is typical neon operating voltage.)
The LDR's slow time constant should keep the reading stable during mains zero-cross.

See [International Light](https://www.intl-lighttech.com/applications/light-sources/neon-lamps) for more details on the neons.